# Javascript loop not appending value in each container

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be such a simple fix, but I think I've been stuck on this issue for way to long. Can someone spare a pair of eyes and see where I'm messing up?

I'm pulling data from a json file and trying to append the right value with the right container. Right now it's placing all the values in the first div container.

```
var metaDataArray = resultSet.searchResult[i].metadatatoshow;

        for (var xx = 0; xx < metaDataArray.length; xx++) {
            var metaDataContainer = "<div id='itemMetaDataContainer_"+xx+"'>Meta Data:" + metaDataArray[xx].name + "-</div>"

            for (var xxx = 0; xxx < metaDataArray[xx].meta_values.length; xxx++) {

                $('#itemMetaDataContainer_'+xx).append(metaDataArray[xx].meta_values[xxx]);

            }

            itemDetailsDiv.append(metaDataContainer);
        }
```

Comment: `#itemMetaDataContainer_XX` is still a string when you try to append some content to it. If it's not, you've multiplied `id`s within the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to select a container before you append it to the details div. try appending the data values array to your container the following way:

```
var metaDataArray = resultSet.searchResult[i].metadatatoshow;

for (var xx = 0; xx < metaDataArray.length; xx++) {
    var metaDataContainer = $("<div id='itemMetaDataContainer_" + xx + "'>Meta Data:" + metaDataArray[xx].name + "-</div>");
    for (var xxx = 0; xxx < metaDataArray[xx].meta_values.length; xxx++) {
        metaDataContainer.append(metaDataArray[xx].meta_values[xxx]);
    }
    itemDetailsDiv.append(metaDataContainer);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

a jQuery object holds the plain html element in index [0] (assuming its not an array).

 to get the html out of `metaDataContainer` you can find it in `metaDataContainer[0]`

therefore, in order to append the jQuery object `metaDataContainer` to the plain html element `itemDetailsDiv`, you need to do the following:

```
itemDetailsDiv.innerHtml + = metaDataContainer[0];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is a plain JavaScript solution:

```
var metaDataArray = resultSet.searchResult[i].metadatatoshow;

for (var xx = 0; xx < metaDataArray.length; xx++) {
    //initializing the html string with the container opening tag and the description:
    var metaDataContainer = "<div id='itemMetaDataContainer_" + xx + "'>Meta Data:" + metaDataArray[xx].name;

    //looping through the values and adding them to the html string:
    for (var xxx = 0; xxx < metaDataArray[xx].meta_values.length; xxx++) {
        //create a span for each value and add it to the html string
        metaDataContainer+="<span>" + metaDataArray[xx].meta_values[xxx] + "</span>";
        //add a line break just for aesthetics, you can change to suit your formatting requirements
        metaDataContainer+="<br/>";
    }
    //finish by adding a closing tag for the container
    metaDataContainer+="-</div>"

    //append the new html string to the details div
    itemDetailsDiv.innerHtml +=metaDataContainer;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! But now I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in console

Comment: probably because of your `itemDetailsDiv`, is it a jQuery object? because if its not, `append()` wont work on it

Comment: It's not a jQuery object. Is there a way to do this without using jQuery?

Comment: you already used jQuery as soon as you used the `$("")` selector. if you would like to append it without jQuery, you will need to extract the html object from the jQuery object and add it to the inner Html of the details div, i will update my answer.

Comment: Do I replace itemDetailsDiv.append(metaDataContainer) with your updated code? Or place it in the nested loop?

Comment: simply replace that line with the one from the update.

Comment: I still get the same error for line metaDataContainer.append(metaDataArray[xx].meta_values[xxx]); undefined is not a function

Comment: yes, it uses jQuery. have you included jquery? or you want to do it in plain javascript? (you tagged the question with jquery, i assumed you wanted to use jquery)

Comment: I rather do it in vanilla javascript. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case its simple string manipulations,  all you need to do is add the closing tag for the container after the nested loop, and inside the nested loop you create html strings for the child elements and append to the container html string. I will update my answer with vanilla js example In about an hout once i get to a pc(on mobile now).

Comment: i have upodated the answer